# Corsa life 1.2 oil/engine problem

Tags: engine, oil-leak, opel, vauxhall

No lights have came on at all to tell me the car was running low on oil. Drove home today and smoke was coming from under the hood and burning smell. The car is still turning over but when I looked at the oil dipstick it is totally dry so no idea how long I have been running with low oil and when im tried to put some in it is pouring straight out the bottom of the car. There is also oil all over the hood and the engine like there was some sort of explosion! Question is...is this worth a fix or have I damaged the engine.

Answer (score 0):

The oil light only comes on when pressure drops below 7-psi. It's not an oil level sensor. The car maker expects you to check that with the dipstick. If oil is leaking you've either puncture a hole in the pan, oil filter or you've got a leaking oil line to the turbo )if equipped)

Comment: the oil line to a turbo only leaks when the engine is running,so this have to be the oil pan/oil filter this can happen if you hit an object,speedbump or other things.

Comment: Can't recommend if it's worth a fix until we know year, make and miles. Body condition would help too.

Comment: Its a corsa life 1.2 its a 07 plate and has 87453 on the mileage.

Comment: Car is still starting and no unusual sounds from it. The oil pressure switch looks damaged oil leaking from it and some on the top of the bonnet right above it as if it has had a bit of an explosion. I havent hit anything that I can think of for the oil pan to be damaged.